webview at react native show white screen before load complete
I tried to show content using webview but screen shows me white screen before webpage load complete .
I want to change color white to #131416. but style option doesn't work.
how can I fix this?
   <WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          source={{
            uri: currentUrl.current,
          }}
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#131416" }}
          onLoadStart={handleOnLoadStart}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          allowFileAccess={true}
          onMessage={handleMessage}
          onNavigationStateChange={setNavigationState}
          userAgent={userAgent}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          onLoadEnd={handleOnLoadEnd}
          onContentProcessDidTerminate={() => {
            RNRestart.restart();
          }}
        />

I tried change styles and used renderLoading props but doesn't work.

Wrap WebView (transparent background) with View and define the desired background color there.
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
  <WebView
    style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://google.com',
    }}
  />
</View>

